# Hide the element within the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, jquery-events

I'm duplicating the div `#Play_Start`. I have a event within div On select of Play from Dropdown it hides the Green div with Play text.

It works fine on first div. But doesn't work on duplicated div.
I want to hide the green div on selection of dropdown Play option from particular div.
E.g : from div one dropdown selected play option it should hide the green div of only that div not other.

and same with other divs. It should hide the green div on selection of dropdown option from same div.

```
My fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/2/
```

at the moment it only works for first div and not for other duplicated divs.

Comment: I believe, controls with duplicate Id is causing issue. `$('#Inputs-Control').val()` will fetch value of first.

Comment: any work around ? Please suggest an example would be great.

Comment: Did you get an error message that told you that if you link to JS Fiddle you must also include the code in the question? Did you deal with that by telling Stackoverflow that the link to JS Fiddle was your code? Don't do that. **Put your code in the question**. You can [embed live examples](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) without resorting to third party hosting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems on your code,

1. You are duplicating the id's. Id should be unique. You need to replace it with class names.
2. You don't need to write inline function calls from elements. you can use jQuery to bind events to the elements.
3. Since you are creating the elements dynamically, you need to use delegates for binding the elements.

Then you can use like this,

```
$(document).on("change", ".Inputs-Control", function () {
    $(this).closest(".Play_Start").find('.IconTest').hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/4/)

Comment: it hides all the Green Buttons

Answer (score 0):

Don't use IDs when duplicating elements. You should only have 1 ID (unique). You should use classes.

I think this is what you are looking for. I'm not going to be writing your code for you - but you should be able to figure it out using this.

```
$('.input-control').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val === "0"){
         $(this).parent().find('.hide-me').hide();
    }
});
```